# Extract characters after focal character "."

Tags: regex, r

This matches everything after the first `"."` and replaces it with `""`

```
gsub( "\\..*$", "", c("BB1.CARR"))
```

But I am struggling in how to reverse this condition so as to replace all characters before the `"."` with `""` or swap from `gsub` to a function that *keeps* the string before the `.` like `grep`.

How do I produce `"CARR"` without resorting to `strplit` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match everything (`.*`) before and including the dot (`\\.`):

```
> gsub( ".*\\.", "", c("BB1.CARR"))
[1] "CARR"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative

```
> sub( "^[[:alnum:]]+\\.", "", c("BB1.CARR"))
[1] "CARR"
```

Option #2

```
> sub( "\\w+\\.", "", c("BB1.CARR"))
[1] "CARR"
```

Option #3

```
> sub( ".*\\.(.*)$", "\\1", c("BB1.CARR"))
[1] "CARR"
```